# Issue with rest end point in Weblogic server

Tags: java, rest, weblogic12c

I have created rest api with following url-pattern in web.xml file.
/service/*

Its working fine in tomcat server with URL http://localhost:9080/context/service/test

however, in the WebLogic server, its getting failed with the above URL. But when I am using the following URL, It's working fine.

http://localhost:9080/context/resources/test

I am not sure why given first given URL not working with the web-logic server.

Please suggest.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

In web logic by default context name is given as resources( you can check in WADL file in web logic console resource folder), however you may further overwrite if required.